# Separation Axioms

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to show that, for a  a topologycal space $X$, $X$ is $T_1$ iff $\{x\}'=\emptyset $ for all $x\in X.$

( $X$ is $T_1$ if for any $x, y \in X$ exist open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $x\in U-V$ and $y\in V-U$ ).

($\Leftarrow$ ) if $\{x\}'=\emptyset $ then $\overline{\{x\}}=\{x\}' \cup \{x\}=\phi \cup \{x\}=\{x\}$, ie, $\{x\}$ is a closed set.

Then taking $U=X-\{y\} \text{  and  } V=X-\{x\}$ we're done.

But and the other implication ($\Rightarrow$) I only prove that $\{x\}$ is a closed set. This implies that $\{x\}'=\emptyset$? or this side not hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, if you already showed that $\{x\}$ is a closed set, you have shown that $\{x\}' \subseteq \{x\}$. For any space $x$ is not in $\{x\}'$ (any neighbourhood of $x$ *cannot* intersect $\{x\}$ in a point different from $x$, as there are no such points!), so $\{x\}'$ can only be the remaining subset of $\{x\}$, namely $\emptyset$.

Comment: thanks! i appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

It holds. If not. Then there exists a point $\xi\in \{x\}'$ such that for any open set containing $\xi$ will meets two distinct points (at least) of the set $\{x\}$. This clearly is a contradiction.

Comment: @OrEsc You are welcome!